# How to load 'isSubmitted()-method' (defined in service controller) into the main controller?

Tags: symfony

I've put a registration form in a method so, that I can use it in different places.

My service registration controller looks like this:

```
public function loadRegisterForm()
{
    $user = new User();
    $form = $this->createForm(RegistrationType::class, $user);
    $form->handleRequest($this->request);

    $errors = "";

    if ($form->isSubmitted())
    {
        if ($form->isValid())
        {
            $password = $this->get('security.password_encoder')
                ->encodePassword($user, $user->getPlainPassword());
            $user->setPassword($password);

            $user->setIsActive(1);
            $user->setLastname('none');
            $user->setCountry('none');

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();
        }
        else
        {
            $errors = $this->get('validator')->validate($form);
        }
    }

    $parametersArray['form'] = $form;
    $parametersArray['errors'] = $errors;

    return $parametersArray;
}
```

services.yml looks like this:

```
register_form_service:
    class: ImmoBundle\Controller\Security\RegistrationController
    calls:
        - [setContainer, ["@service_container"]]
```

And the main controller where I load the service controller:

```
private function indexAction()
{
    /**
     * Load register form
     */
    $registerForm = $this->get('register_form_service');
    $registerParameters = $registerForm->loadRegisterForm();
    $registerParameters['form']->handleRequest($request);

    return $this->render(
        'ImmoBundle::Pages/mainPage.html.twig',
        array(
            'register_form'  => $registerParameters['form']->createView(),
            'errors'         => $registerParameters['errors'],
            )
    );
}
```

The form itself is well rendered, so there is no problem. However nothing happens if I try to submit the form. I know that I should add the following line to the main controller

```
if ($registerParameters['form']->isSubmitted())
{
    // add to db
}
```

But is there any way to do it only in a service controller?

Comment: What is `$this->request` in your service? In my opinion, you should pass the Request you handle in your main controller as a parameter of your `loadRegisterForm` method, and get this Request handled by your form.

Comment: Thank you, just passed the request to the loadRegisterForm method and it works now fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a service definition to inject the container into your controller. If the controller extends `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller` all services are accesible via `->get()`. Next to that, `$form->isValid()` already checks whether the form is submitted.

Why is your action private? It should be public, and it need to get the `Request` object as it's first parameter:

```
public function indexAction(Request $request) 
{
    $user = new User();
    $form = $this->createForm(RegistrationType::class, $user);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        // Do something here
    }
}
```

See http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#handling-form-submissions

Comment: Yes, it should be public indeed :) I figured out that problem by passing request to loadRegisterForm. Anyway, thanks for the tip about accessing service through '->get()'!